# Creating a Linux TFS workspace - argument error

Tags: linux, tfs

I'm trying to create a new `TFS` workspace in my `CentOS` virtual machine, in order to then use `TFS` with `Jenkins`. However, despite following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y901w7se.aspx) Microsoft post, it keeps telling me `An argument error occurred: Only one name may be supplied when editing a workspace`.

```
[me@centos ~]$  tf workspace /new /collection:http://10.9.8.7:8081/tfs/Col /permission:Public tfs /login:dev\onlyme,Password1
An argument error occurred: Only one name may be supplied when editing a workspace.
[me@centos ~]$
[me@centos ~]$ tf workspace /new collection:http://10.9.8.7:8081/tfs/Col tfs
An argument error occurred: Only one name may be supplied when editing a workspace.
[me@centos ~]$
```

Using the Syntax from the link above, I can't see where I'm going wrong (bearing in mind I've tried every variation of command one above). Even when I use the example in command two above(expecting an authentication error or something else), it tells me the same thing.

Also, this is a brand new VM and therefore I'm not sure why the error message states that the command is *editing* a workspace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your problem is you are using slashes '/' instead of dashes '-' for the options. The Unix tf app conforms to unix syntax for the options.

Comment: Yep, if you're on a Mac don't use the slashes. Thanks for the help Paul.